# Hosting ASP Web API in IIS Without All The ASP Overhead?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've read from Scott Hanselman that a self-host console application of ASP Web API has 50% speed efficiency over a traditional ASP.NET MVC Web API project, since it doesn't have as much internal overhead.

My question is, what if I want to host a Web API in IIS? Can't use a Console Application, but still want to reap the benefits of not having the entire ASP.net framework overhead for only needing a simple web API?

Comment: Can you please add a link?

Comment: Was Scott Hanselman talking about the overhead of ASP.NET or was he talking about the overhead of ASP.NET MVC (on top of ASP.NET)?

Comment: @tgolisch ASP.NET MVC doesn't add any overhead to an ASP.NET Web API as they are independent.

Answer (score 1):

It is 'theoretically' possible with OWIN. Some one asked the same question [here](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/442574).